# Not hacky way to make RN think it’s TV even when it’s not (modifying uiMode?)

Tags: android, react-native, expo, android-tv

So I need my app to run like it’s Android TV on an AOSP Android box. As a POC I tried to change the function in node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Utilities/Platform.android.js from

```
get isTV(): boolean {
    return this.constants.uiMode === 'tv';
  }
```

to

```
  get isTV(): boolean {
    return true;
  },
```

And it works fine on the box. I would like a less hacky way to do it though. The solution would seem to be able to change uiMode to tv, but I found out it’s not a param you can change in expo’s app.json nor does it look like changeable from the JS code. Is there a way to do it, or another way I didn't think of to achieve this same result without changing RN code directly?

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I didn't find any way to actually change this as a parameter thing, but I ended up using [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) to record my edit of RN and avoid the hassle to fork.